# Rails expanding fields with scope, PG does not like it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model of Widgets. Widgets belong to a Store model, which belongs to an Area model, which belongs to a Company. At the Company model, I need to find all associated widgets. Easy:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.in_company(company)
    includes(:store => {:area => :company}).where(:companies => {:id => company.id})
  end
end
```

Which will generate this beautiful query:

```
> Widget.in_company(Company.first).count

SQL (50.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "widgets"."id") FROM "widgets" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "widgets"."store_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "stores"."area_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "areas"."company_id" WHERE "companies"."id" = 1
 => 15088
```

But, I later need to use this scope in more complex scope. The problem is that AR is expanding the query by selecting individual fields, which fails in PG because selected fields must in the GROUP BY clause or the aggregate function.

Here is the more complex scope.

```
def self.sum_amount_chart_series(company, start_time)
  orders_by_day = Widget.in_company(company).archived.not_void.
                  where(:print_datetime => start_time.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).
                  group(pg_print_date_group).
                  select("#{pg_print_date_group} as print_date, sum(amount) as total_amount")

end

def self.pg_print_date_group
  "CAST((print_datetime + interval '#{tz_offset_hours} hours') AS date)"
end
```

And this is the select it is throwing at PG:

```
> Widget.sum_amount_chart_series(Company.first, 1.day.ago)

SELECT "widgets"."id" AS t0_r0, "widgets"."user_id" AS t0_r1,<...BIG SNIP, YOU GET THE IDEA...> FROM "widgets" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "widgets"."store_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "areas" ON "areas"."id" = "stores"."area_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "areas"."company_id" WHERE "companies"."id" = 1 AND "widgets"."archived" = 't' AND "widgets"."voided" = 'f' AND ("widgets"."print_datetime" BETWEEN '2011-04-24 00:00:00.000000' AND '2011-04-25 23:59:59.999999') GROUP BY CAST((print_datetime + interval '-7 hours') AS date)
```

Which generates this error:

> PGError: ERROR:  column
>   "widgets.id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT
>   "widgets"."id" AS t0_r0,
>   "widgets"."user_id...

How do I rewrite the Widget.in_company scope so that AR does not expand the select query to include every Widget model field?

Comment: Rails 3 presumably?  I had a simpler case in Rails3/Heroku where I was not select specific columns - so it was doing a select * and got this error - fixed it by adding specific column selections - but you are doing that.... :(

Answer (score 10):

As Frank explained, PostgreSQL will reject any query which doesn't return a reproducible set of rows.

Suppose you've a query like:

```
select a, b, agg(c)
from tbl
group by a
```

PostgreSQL will reject it because `b` is left unspecified in the `group by` statement. Run that in MySQL, by contrast, and it will be accepted. In the latter case, however, fire up a few inserts, updates and deletes, and the order of the rows on disk pages ends up different.

If memory serves, implementation details are so that MySQL will actually sort by a, b and return the first b in the set. But as far as the SQL standard is concerned, the behavior is unspecified -- and sure enough, PostgreSQL does *not* always sort before running aggregate functions.

Potentially, this might result in different values of `b` in result set in PostgreSQL. And thus, PostgreSQL yields an error unless you're more specific:

```
select a, b, agg(c)
from tbl
group by a, b
```

What Frank highlighted is that, in PostgreSQL 9.1, if `a` is the primary key, than you can leave `b` unspecified -- the planner has been taught to ignore subsequent group by fields when applicable primary keys imply a unique row.

For your problem in particular, you need to specify your group by as you currently do, *plus* every field that you're basing your aggregate onto, i.e. `"widgets"."id", "widgets"."user_id", [snip]` but not stuff like `sum(amount)`, which are the aggregate function calls.

As an off topic side note, I'm not sure how your ORM/model works but the SQL it's generating isn't optimal. Many of those left outer joins seem like they should be inner joins. This will result in allowing the planner to pick an appropriate join order where applicable.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL version 9.1 ([beta at this moment](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news.1313)) might fix your problem, but only if there is a functional dependency on the primary key.

From the release notes:

> Allow non-GROUP BY columns in the
>   query target list when the primary key
>   is specified in the GROUP BY clause
>   (Peter Eisentraut)
>
> Some other database system already
>   allowed this behavior, and because of
>   the primary key, the result is
>   unambiguous.

You could run a test and see if it fixes your problem. If you can wait for the production release, this can fix the problem without changing your code.

Comment: While this does shed some light on the issue, upgrading to a higher version of PostgreSQL isn't a feasible option for many Rails developers, as Heroku runs on PostgreSQL 8.3.  I will award my bounty to someone who can come up with a simple example that gives the same error as well as another way of writing the query to get the same intended information.  In the event of more than one person delivering on this, the bounty will go to who can provide a clearer explanation on the error and how to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly simplify your life by storing all dates in a standard time-zone. Changing dates with time-zones should really be done in the view as a user convenience. This alone should save you a lot of pain.

If you're already in production write a migration to create a `normalised_date` column wherever it would be helpful.

nrI propose that the other problem here is the use of raw SQL, which rails won't poke around for you. To avoid this try using the gem called Squeel (aka Metawhere 2) http://metautonomo.us/projects/squeel/

If you use this you should be able to remove hard coded SQL and let rails get back to doing its magic.

For example:

```
.select("#{pg_print_date_group} as print_date, sum(amount) as total_amount")
```

becomes (once your remove the need for normalising the date):

```
.select{sum(amount).as(total_amount)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I figured it out.

First, let me apologize to those who thought I might be having an SQL or Postgres issue, it is not. The issue is with ActiveRecord and the SQL it is generating.

The answer is... use *.joins* instead of *.includes*. So I just changed the line in the top code and it works as expected.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.in_company(company)
    joins(:store => {:area => :company}).where(:companies => {:id => company.id})
  end
end
```

I'm guessing that when using .includes, ActiveRecord is trying to be smart and use JOINS in the SQL, but it's not smart enough for this particular case and was generating that ugly SQL to select all associated columns.

However, all the replies have taught me quite a bit about Postgres that I did not know, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

sort in mysql:

```
> ids = [11,31,29]
=> [11, 31, 29]
> Page.where(id: ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join(',')})")
```

in postgres:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["case"]
  ids.each_with_index.map do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "end"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end

User.where(:id => [3,2,1]).order_by_ids([3,2,1]).map(&:id) 
#=> [3,2,1]
```